# Issue converting varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to put all the data from the years 1928-2000 into the year 2001-2021 (for practice purpose). The result I'm looking for is all the order date should be in the format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm". there will not be any orders with the order date before 2001. Original datatype of `orderdate` is `datetime`: "1928-10-10 00:00:00.000 "

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Could someone please tell me how to solve this? I tried to convert it to `datetime` but still doesn't work. the format has to be "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm"

```
UPDATE Orders
SET OrderDate = CASE 
                   WHEN YEAR(orderdate) BETWEEN 1928 AND 1948 
                      THEN CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(orderdate) + 73) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, orderdate, 21), 5, 20) 
                   WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) BETWEEN 1949 AND 1968 
                      THEN CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(orderdate) + 52) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, orderdate, 21), 5, 20) 
                   WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) BETWEEN 1969 AND 1988 
                      THEN CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(orderdate) + 32) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, orderdate, 21), 5, 20)
                   ELSE CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(orderdate) + 21) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, orderdate, 21), 5, 20) 
                END
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) < 2001
```

Comment: Please explain wha the logic is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, what is the type of `orderdate`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff i'm trying to put all the data from the years 1928-2000 into the year 2001-2021 (for practice purpose). the result i'm looking for is all the order date should be in the format of "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm". there will not be any orders with the order date before 2001. data type of order date is datetime and right now it looks like "1928-10-10 00:00:00.000 ".

Comment: [edit] your question so that its complete for anyone to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I get it now.  You are just trying to add a variable number of years to the order date -- probably to make fictitious data or something (the reason isn't important).

You are doing all sorts of unnecessary conversions, when all you need is `dateadd()`:

```
set orderdate = dateadd(year,
                        (case when year(orderdate) between 1928 and 1948
                              then 73
                              when year(orderdate) between 1949 and 1968
                              then 52
                              when year(orderdate) between 1969 and 1988
                              then 32
                              else 21
                         end),
                        orderdate
                       )
```

Comment: hi @Dale K, yes I'm making up some data. i'm trying to convert "1928-10-10 00:00:00.000" to "2001-10-10 00:00:00.000".  So basically I'd like to change the older years to the most recent 20 years. I'd like to only change the year (depending on which year it is, then i added a number to make sure the new year is between 2001 and 2021), and keep the rest of the date the same. I hope I explained right this time...